Why can't a $1\times 3$ system $Ax=b$ have a particular solution $x_p = (2,4,0)$ and nullspace $x_n =$ any multiple of $(1,1,1)$
Why can't a $1\times 3$ system $Ax=b$ have a particular solution $x_p = (2,4,0)$ and nullspace $x_n =$ any multiple of $(1,1,1)$
This question is from Gilbert Strang's "Introduction to Linear Algebra". I came up with
$$Ax=b$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ \end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}-2 \\ \end{bmatrix}
$$
which is satisfied by the solution
$$x=
\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 4 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}+c
\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}
$$
Is my error definitional in that a $1\times 3$ system cannot have rank greater than one, so there needs to be two special solutions, and furthermore, the special solutions in this case, would require both a $0$ and a $1$ component?  What am I missing conceptually here?

The body of the question should contain all the context needed. The title can sometimes be the same as the first sentence, but it is not the first sentence of the question.

Got it, thanks!

You are right, the rank is $1$, so number of free variables will be $2$, same as saying that nullity is $2$. So, the homogeneous solution will be $2D$. The homogeneous solution can be written as $$\mathbf{x}_h=c\begin{bmatrix}1\1\1\end{bmatrix}+d\begin{bmatrix}1\1\0\end{bmatrix}$$

Thanks, that makes sense that the null space is a plane.  I noticed that $\begin{bmatrix}A & b \ \end{bmatrix}$ is already in reduced row echelon form and I applied the algorithm for determining the complete soultion from $\begin{bmatrix}R & d \ \end{bmatrix}$and got $$x=\begin{bmatrix}-2 \ 0 \ 0 \ \end{bmatrix}+ c\begin{bmatrix}1 \ 1 \ 0 \ \end{bmatrix}+d\begin{bmatrix}0 \ 0 \ 1 \ \end{bmatrix}$$ Is this the same nullspace as the one above?
